# Calculate time ranges by by starting dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Saying, I have a table with "Start" dates

```
ID     Start
1      null      
2      2001-1-1
3      2002-1-1
```

Now, I need to calculate effective time ranges for each record in a effective way:

```
ID     Start     Finish
1      null      2000-12-31
2      2001-1-1  2001-12-31
3      2002-1-1  null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LEAD:

```
create table #dates
(
    ID int,
    Start date
)

insert into #dates values(1,null),(2,'01-jan-2001'),(3,'01-jan-2002')

select ID,
    Start,
    DATEADD(DD, -1, LEAD(Start,1) over (order by Start)) AS Finish
from #dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`.

**Query**

```
select t1.[ID], t1.[Start], 
dateadd(day, -1, t2.[Start]) as [Finish]
from [your_table_name] t1
left join [your_table_name] t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID - 1;
```

**[`Demo 1`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/598396/calculate-time-ranges-by-by-starting-dates)**

As HABO mentioned, if Id is not in the correct order. Then give a row number order by `ID` column.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
  select [row_num] = row_number() over(
    order by [ID]
  ),*
  from [your_table_name]
)
select t1.[ID], t1.[Start], 
dateadd(day, -1, t2.[Start]) as [Finish]
from cte t1
left join cte t2
on t1.[row_num] = t2.[row_num] - 1;
```

**[`Demo 2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/598396/calculate-time-ranges-by-by-starting-dates)**

Comment: It's worth noting that this requires that the `ID` values remain dense.